# bbPress Remove Forum posts after 4 months

Tags: php, html, wordpress, bbpress

I would like to remove forum posts from my marketplace forum that haven't been active for 4 months.
I've been looking around online but the only answers I've found were from 5+ years ago and don't work (anymore). 
I've tried doing it with PHP, and looked around on the bbPress website for developer documentation, but that doesn't exist yet, and has been under construction for around 5 years.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a plugin on the bbPress forum that seems to have done the trick.

Link to plugin: https://bbpress.org/forums/topic/auto-remove-forum-post-bbpress/